# ListView in Android change item View

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on `ListView` and I need when click on item the image change the item view in my list as my photo. but when I scroll down in my list I found other item is clicked . and this is my code

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if (i != lastpostion) {
        viewselected = getViewByPosition(lastpostion, listView);
        play = viewselected.findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause = viewselected.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    isfound = true;
    play = view.findViewById(R.id.play);
    pause = view.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //Toast.makeText(this,""+listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(this,""+listView.getChildCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    lastpostion = i;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this would make sens to change your code like this

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (i == lastpostion) { // if the user clicked here before then we set it on pause
            viewselected = getViewByPosition(i, listView);
            play = viewselected.findViewById(R.id.play);
            pause = viewselected.findViewById(R.id.pause);
            play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           //maybe after you pause it isFound variable should go to false;
        } else { 
        // else we make play visible
        isfound = true;
        play = view.findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause = view.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lastpostion = i;
       }
    }
```

Comment: so the problem is , the wrong item gets clicked ? that you didn;t click?